# Understanding Javascript super method emulation code

Tags: javascript, inheritance, super

I was reading [this article](https://www.salsify.com/blog/engineering/super-methods-in-javascript) about super methods in Javascript. Right at the bottom, there's an approach used by the author, which essentially involves adding a name property to every method function object and using it to find a matching method on the prototype chain of the current object calling super.

I'll replicate the [code](https://gist.github.com/dfreeman/c877e0bc0ccb4ffbc33e#file-super-js) below:

```
var Base = function() {};

// Use the regular Backbone extend, but tag methods with their name
Base.extend = function() {
  var Subclass = Backbone.Model.extend.apply(this, arguments);
  _.each(Subclass.prototype, function(value, name) {
    if (_.isFunction(value)) {
      value._methodName = name;
    }
  });
  return Subclass;
};

// Define a special `super` property that locates the super implementation of the caller
Object.defineProperty(Base.prototype, "super", {
  get: function get() {
    var impl = get.caller,
      name = impl._methodName,
      foundImpl = this[name] === impl,
      proto = this;

    while (proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)) {
      if (!proto[name]) {
        break;
      } else if (proto[name] === impl) {
        foundImpl = true;
      } else if (foundImpl) {
        return proto[name];
      }
    }

    if (!foundImpl) throw "`super` may not be called outside a method implementation";
  }
});
```

It uses Underscore.js and Backbone.js, which I'm not very familiar with, but their usage is not where the doubt lies.

When setting the `super` property getter, 4 variables are declared: `impl`, `name`, `foundImpl` and `proto`.

`impl` holds the method that called `super`, obtained through `get.caller`. `name` is the name of the method that called `super` (or `undefined` if `super` is not called from within a method). `proto` holds the object from where the method was invoked, whose prototype chain will be transversed until we find the super method.

Now `foundImpl` is a bit confusing for me. It is a boolean, and at first is assigned the value of `this[name] === impl`. Since `this` points to the object from where the method is being invoked from, `this[name]` will return the method itself, which will be `===` to `impl`. This will be true everytime, **unless** `name` is `undefined` (we call `super` outside a method).

The line `while(proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto))` then starts iterating through the prototype chain of the calling object, starting from the immediate parent, until it reaches `null`.

`if(!proto[name])` checks if there is a method with the same name in the current prototype. If there isn't it breaks out of the loop and if `foundImpl` is false an error will be thrown. As stated before, the only situation where I can see this happening is if `super` is called outside a method, where `name` will be `undefined` and thus `this[name] === impl` will be false as well. Otherwise, since `foundImpl` will already be true from the beginning.

`else if (proto[name] === impl)` will check if the current prototype method with the same name is strictly equal to the method that is calling `super`. I honestly can't think of a situation where this will be true, since for `super` to be called from a method it will have to be overriden, making both different function objects. For example:

```
var a = { method: function(){ return "Hello!"; } };
var b = Object.create(a);
console.log(a.method === b.method); //true
b.method = function(){ return "Hello World!"; };
console.log(a.method === b.method); //false
```

Maybe this is just a safety check after all and this conditional will never be reached?

Finally, `else if (foundImpl)` will check is `foundImpl` is true (which it will likely be on the first loop iteration, except on the special case stated above) and return the current `proto[name]` method if it is.

---

So my doubt is what is the point of that second conditional: `else if (proto[name] === impl)`? What case is it covering? What is the role of `foundImpl` after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I haven't thought about that blog post in quite a while! I believe most evergreen browsers have dropped support for `arguments.caller` at this point, which makes demo code a little hard to write, but I'll do my best to explain

The line you called out as being confusing is `foundImpl = this[name] === impl`, which looks at first glance like it would always evaluate to `true`. The reason it's needed (and actually what interested me about "the `super` problem" in the first place) is cases where you have chained `super` calls.

Consider a setup like this:

```
const Base = /* ... */;

const First = Base.extend({
  sayHello() {
    console.log('First#sayHello()');
  }
});

const Middle = First.extend({
  sayHello() {
    this.super();
    console.log('Middle#sayHello()');
  }
});

const Last = Middle.extend({
  sayHello() {
    this.super();
    console.log('Last#sayHello()');
  }
});
```

If I call `new Last().sayHello()`, that `super` getter will be invoked twice. The first time, as you say `this[name] === impl` will be true right off the bat.

In the *second* call, though, the caller will be the function from `Middle`, but `this[name]` will be the function from `Last`, so `this[name] === impl` will be false.

Execution will then continue into the prototype-traversal loop, and after going up one step, we'll find that `proto[name] === impl`, so `foundImpl` will be set to true, and we'll proceed through the loop one more time and correctly return the function from `Base`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan, perfect explanation! It all makes sense now :)